# Remote SQL connection in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database on my website, say **example1.com** . I want to access a table of this database from my other website, say **example2.com** . I have added *example2.com* in the remote MySQL access users list.

What else will I need to do to achieve this ? Can anyone help me with an example.

Comment: Why did you include sql-server tag if the question is about MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the database domain as the host of your database connection and make the ip of the other website trusted for the first website host, or to have access via ssh, then you can connect ^^.

Comment: And don't forget to open the port that MySQL uses.

Comment: Sorry @Manuel...might be a silly question, but can you please explain how do I make second website trusted for the first one ?

And by "host" do you mean I have to use *example1.com* instead of *localhost* when I try to access the database from example2.com ??

Comment: Also some guys told me API can help to access remote database. Are these the same thing ?

Comment: Well, you might want to ask to your hosting provider or the owner of the host-server containing the database where you want to connect, if it has an API, you don't need to set a connection, you use the API to request the information you need.